# Replacement for JSONCPP

Tags: c++, json, jsoncpp

The problem is that JSONCPP has a bug. It does not read JSON file properly.
We store 3D models in JSON and today we got a model that crash our app.

In short if we load that JSON (120KB) and save it new file we get 80KB.
All vertexes are missing but normals, tangents, etc is still in file.

Please, recommend C++ JSON parser that is similar to JSONCPP as much as possible.

Upgrading JSONCPP does not help.

Comment: Can you paste a link to an example JSON that is misread? If there really is a bug, it can be found and fixed.

Comment: The model is copyrighted but it is only lod4. So I guess I can do http://pastiebin.com/523a371ddd659  Last VERT is missing. I do load and save with http://pastie.org/private/0svdsiejjy1ongw6snndsa

Comment: That JSON file a created with JSONCPP.

Comment: That JSON is invalid. Look at lines 1389 to 1392.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz thank you for help. Please answer this question and I will mark as answered

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JSON you are using is invalid. Look at lines 1389 to 1392.

```
                 [ -0.5321721434593201, 0.0, 0.8466361761093140 ],
                 [ -0.5321721434593201, 0.0, 0.8466361761093140 ],
                 [ -0.5321721434593201, 0.0, 0.8466361761093140 ],
                 [ -0.5321721434593201, 0.0, 0.8466361761093140 ],
                 [ -1.#IND00000000000, -1.#IND00000000000, -1.#IND00000000000 ],
                 [ -1.#IND00000000000, -1.#IND00000000000, -1.#IND00000000000 ],
                 [ -1.#IND00000000000, -1.#IND00000000000, -1.#IND00000000000 ],
                 [ -1.#IND00000000000, -1.#IND00000000000, -1.#IND00000000000 ],
                 [ -0.5321709513664246, 0.0, -0.8466369509696960 ],
                 [ -0.5321709513664246, 0.0, -0.8466369509696960 ],
                 [ -0.5321710109710693, 0.0, -0.8466369509696960 ],
                 [ -0.5321710109710693, 0.0, -0.8466369509696960 ],
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [cJSON](https://github.com/DaveGamble/cJSON), which is a good ultralight weight JSON parser in ANSI C . We use them in commercial deployments for complex data transactions. I guess 3D models would come down to complex data, you can give a try.